# Flarum connection timeout after installing Let's Encrypt SSL certificate

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, flarum

After installing Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on my forum.mydomain.com ubuntu 20.04 server, which is running a LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and Ubuntu 20.04. I have followed the instructions on the Flarum documentation, but when I try to access the forum using HTTPS, I get a connection timeout error.

I am not sure what else to try. Can anyone help me?

ps: I'm using cloudflare to manage DNS